# How to crawl/search multiple tables from external SQL database in SP 2010?

Tags: crawling

I was able to crawl a table (from an external SQL database) via SP 2010 and it works great. However, I wanted to have SP crawl multiple tables from that same database and it's not happening. For some reason, it only returns results from that 1 table. I've checked the ECT settings and they have CRUD permissions on all the tables. I don't know what to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Central Administration search configuration, make sure you that when you configure your content source that you check the box "Crawl all external data sources in this Business Data Connectivity Service Application". You should also see all the sources listed with checkboxes if you want to be selective (you can check that all your tables are showing up).

Also, make sure that you have created an External Content Type for each of your tables that you want to crawl.

Do a full crawl of this content source. If you still don't see results, check your crawl logs to identify any problems.